# Improving conditional logic

Tags: javascript

I have a conditional statement that I'd like to improve on if possible as I find it quite unwieldy:

```
    let action

    if(options.add) {
        action = 'ADD'
    } else if(options.update) {
        action = 'UPDATE'
    } else {
        action = 'REMOVE'
    }
```

Is it possible to make this a switch or ternary of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok to me now. But if you still looking for alternatives, Ternary ?

```
let action = options.add ? "ADD" :  (options.update ? "UPDATE" : "REMOVE") ;
```

Comment: Interesting, i was unaware of this type of ternary style

Answer (score 1):

If you want more dynamic solution you could create array of actions and then use find on that array to find that action in object and assign it to variable or set default value of `REMOVE`.

```js
let action;
let options = {add: 1}
let actions = ['add', 'update', 'remove'];

action = (actions
  .find(a => options[a]) || 'remove')
  .toUpperCase();

console.log(action)
```

You can also make a function that will take options object and return action value.

```js
let action;
var actions = ['add', 'update', 'remove'];

function setAction(options = {}) {
  return (actions.find(a => options[a]) || 'remove')
  .toUpperCase();
}

action = setAction({add: 1});
console.log(action)

action = setAction();
console.log(action)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want ternary operation

```
let action;
action = (options.add) ? 'ADD' : ((options.update) ? 'UPDATE' : 'REMOVE');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
action = options.add && 'ADD' || options.update && 'UPDATE' || 'REMOVE'
```